# It is possible to create a custom email response when sender's email is in the text and subject but not "from"

Tags: wordpress, customization

I have a wordpress.com blog. When people sign up to follow blog, wordpress sends me an email. I know there are mail programs like mail chimp, aweber, etc. but with the .com platform my follower numbers require that mail goes through wordpress.com.

If it's doable I would like to be able to set up an auto response from those follower emails.

May be impossible.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a new email forwarder in your CPANEL, pipe that address to a php script, and use the forwarded address as the address wordpress sends your signup notifications to.

Then parse the email, grab the subject and store it to a var like $subject and locate the user's email.

```
preg_match("/[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})/i", $subject, $matches);
$user_email = $matches[0];
```

Then compose your reply email and send it using mail() or phpMailer (best option).

This link explains the entire process and provides the pre-written script for you. All you have to add is the preg_match code above and create your response message and send it.

http://codesamplez.com/programming/email-to-php-script